# wordpress woocommerce range slider

Tags: php, wordpress, select, woocommerce, slider

I want to try change my select drop down box to slider, I have this code I try to change from select to input but don't work. This is my code:

```
echo '<select style="width: 150px;" id="attribute_'.sanitize_title($name).'" name="attribute_'. sanitize_title($name).'">';
    foreach ( $options as $option )
        echo '<option value="' .esc_attr( sanitize_title( $option ) ) . '" class="active">' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) . '</option>';
echo '</select></div>';
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting !

Comment: no I get slider but with all values on output is anyone know how to change this to slider with same function like drop box when I change slider to I have effect on my product